# How to add properties to a list of dicts via a list comprehension in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I have a list of dicts. For each dict, I need to pass one of its properties to a function, and then assign a new property based on the result of that function.

For example:
I have a list of pages of a site. I need to loop through them and, based on the URL, assign the author name to a property in the dict.

```py
for index, page in enumerate(pages):
    pages[index]['author'] = get_author(page['url'])
```

This works. But's cluttered and doesn't feel pythonic. `pages[index]` feels like a thing that I shouldn't have to do in Python.

Is there a way to do this via a list comprehension? Or some other more pythonic way?

```py
pages = [??? for page in pages]
```

Comment: A list comprehension _builds_ a list from an existing list. In your case, you want to _update_ existing list items. A list comprehension is inappropriate for this job.

Comment: @DYZ Makes sense. Is there an alternative here?

Answer (score 6):

You could use such a `list` comprehension:

```
result = [{**page, 'author': get_author(page['url'])} 
          for page in pages]

# This works too:

result = [dict(**page, author=get_author(page['url'])) 
          for page in pages]

# but is less preferred because it will fail for input containing non-string keys
```

This creates a new `dict` for each original `dict` with an extra key, `author`, based on the value of `get_author` as applied to the value corresponding to the `url` key.

Note that it does not *modify* the original `list`.

Example:

```
def get_author(i):
    if i == 1:
        return 'hello'

    else:
        return 'bye'

pages = [{'url': 1},
         {'url': 2}]

result = [{**page, **{'author': get_author(page['url'])}} for page in pages]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[{'url': 1, 'author': 'hello'}, {'url': 2, 'author': 'bye'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

A list comprehension *builds* a list from an existing list. In your case, you want to *update* existing list items. A list comprehension is inappropriate for this job.

Your solution can be somewhat improved, though:

```
for page in pages:
    page['author'] = get_author(page['url'])
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but it was my understanding that modifying `page` directly wouldn't propagate that change to `pages`. I'll check

Comment: @snazzybouche yep, you're incorrect. `list` is mutable and `page` will be a reference to the existing object in `pages`, not a copy or anything like that. This works.

Comment: @snazzybouche You're probably thinking of *reassigning* to the variable name; something like `page = ...`. In this case, you are modifying the object pointed to by `page` inplace, so it'll be fine.

Comment: @gmds Yep, looks like that's where I got mixed up. I was going to say that I've been using enumerate a lot more than I should've, but if that's the case then I've not been doing too bad.

Answer (score 0):

I can see two "pythonic" solutions:

- Creating a new dict out of unpacked page and the new value of 'author':

```
pages = [{**p, 'author': get_author(p['url'])} for p in pages]
```

- A little trick using 'or' operator:

```
pages = [p.update(author=get_author(p['url'])) or  p for p in pages]
```

Since p.update() returns None, `None or p` will always be the updated version of p.

The first one seems to be more readable but I believe that the second one beats the first one in performance.